# Is there a way to load download an image over http directly to the memory?

Tags: javascript, html, http

Usually when someone clicks on an http link for a jpg file, that file gets downloaded into the user's browser cache from where it is loaded into memory. Is there a way to avoid downloading the image to hard disk and just load it directly to the RAM?

Update:
What if you were writing a Windows forms application that fetches images over http. Is it possible then? If yes how?

This not related to anything I am trying to do. I am just curious that's all.

Comment: I'm curious why you would want this to happen?

Comment: Computers have many layers of cache. Chances are the filesystem will have some amount of the image cached in RAM anyway.

Comment: There is a way to prevent an image from downloading to disk.  Use the 'no-store' cache header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the browser behaviour you cannot control.

So if you want that - you need to implement your own browser that does that and ask your users to use it.

Answering your only question asked:

> Is there a way to avoid downloading the image to hard disk and just load it directly to the RAM?

There is no way to tell browser how to process a request exactly.

> Update: What if you were writing a Windows forms application that fetches images over http. Is it possible then? If yes how?

It is already addressed by the first part of my answer.  Again: if it's you who implements an HTTP client/browser - then you're free to do whatever you want.

Comment: Thank you! Would it be also possible to address an update that I added?

Comment: @Foo: my question has already addressed it, but I will do it for the second time.